# Number of matrices satisfying a given property

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix with complex entries.How to find the number of $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ satisfying the equation $A^3=A$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Since any of the $2 \times 2$ matrices $\pmatrix{ ac & bc\cr ad & bd\cr}$ with
$ac + bd = \pm 1$ satisfy the equation, there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 0):

First multiply by $B^{-1}$ and $B$ such that $B^{-1}AB=J$ becomes Jordan.

$$B^{-1}A^3B=(B^{-1}AB)^3=B^{-1}AB$$.

Now we can solve it for Jordan matrices $J$ with $J^3=J$.

A $2x2$ Jordan matrix is either diagonal or of the form $D+N$ where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ has only a one in the top right corner. Notice that $N^2=0$. So, $J^3=D^3+3D^2N$ in that case. To have $J^3=J$ we would need $3J^2N=N$.

Answer (score 0):

$A^2 =I $ has infinite solutions , so $A^3=A$ does too.
$A^2=I$ for all reflection matrices